# Interleaving of putchar() and printf() functions

Tags: c

It is a statement given in K&R that printf() and putchar() can be interleaved. If it true then why is the following code not giving the required output:-

```
#include"stdio.h"
void main()
{
    char c,d;
    printf("Enter the first character\n");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("%c\n",c);
    printf("Enter the second character\n");
    d=getchar();
    putchar(d);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Whenever I am executing this program, the output is as follows:-

```
Enter the first character
a
a
Enter the second character
```

This is the output. This is also happening if I replace printf() by putchar() and scanf() by getchar().  Why is this happpening?

Comment: 1) main() should return int. 2) the second character is in fact the '\n' . 3) try to show the hex value as well, and you will see more.

Comment: You can reuse `c` by the way. (Unless of course you are saving it to use it later on.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `scanf` leaves in the input buffer the `\n` resulting from the <kbd>Return</kbd> press, so your second `getchar()` will acquire this `\n` instead of acquiring another character from the user.

If you want to skip that newline character, you can either instruct the `scanf` to "eat" it:

```
scanf("%c\n",&c);
```

or "eat it" directly with a call to `getchar()`:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
getchar();
```

(notice that these are not exactly equivalent, since the second snippet will eat whatever character happens to be in the buffer, while the first one will remove it only if it's a `\n`)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How exactly does getchar() "eat away" the '\n' ?

Comment: @KunalSuri: `getchar()` extracts the next character from the input buffer; `\n` is the next character in the input buffer. So, it extracts and discards it (since the returned value is not assigned to anything).

Comment: @KingsIndian: It's not K&R code; they'd never write `void main()`.  From the questions, K&R said only that calls to `printf()` and `putchar()` can be interleaved, which they can, as demonstrated by the (flawed) program.  The issue is not the output; it is the input.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I tried removing '\n' from the code. Even then the output for the second character is the same.

Comment: @KunalSuri: you didn't get what I mean. I'm not talking about the `\n` you *write* on `stdout`, but about the one that is in the input buffer due to the fact that when you input the first character you press the *Return* key on the keyboard.

Comment: When you type the response to the 'first character' prompt, you actually type two characters.  For sake of example, you type 'a' and return.  The first `scanf()` reads the 'a', leaving the newline to be read by the `getchar()`.  In fact, you probably don't even have to enter anything before the second output appears.  You could also enter 'ab' (and return) and you'd see the first character is 'a' and the second 'b' and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can correct your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c, d;
    printf("Enter the first character\n");
    scanf("%c\n", &c);    // Ask scanf to read newline and skip
    printf("%c\n", c);

    printf("Enter the second character\n");
    d = getchar();
    putchar(d);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two a's because you type one in which is echoed to the console and then you print it out.

Answer (score -2):

flush the stdin before using `getchar(`)..

In turbo, use `fflush()`..

In gcc, use `__fpurge(stdin)`..(this is available in `<stdio_ext.h>` header)..

Flushing the standard input before scanning anything will solve your issue..

Comment: `fflush` applied to input streams is not portable; also, since when `vim` is a C compiler?

Comment: On Windows, you can `fflush()` an input stream; in standard C and on Unix-based systems, you cannot.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: actually, it's not Windows *per se*, but the CRT implementation from VC++. (just nitpicking, of course)